# Звук при нажатии Button

Tags: c#

Мой пример кода перестал выдавать ошибки, но и звука попросту нет.

Может что-то я делаю не так, или эти библиотеки устарели?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SoundPlayer player = new 
    System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"c:\Ring01.wav");
    player.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать метод `Load()` или `LoadAsync()` перед применением метода `Play()`.

Comment: Попробовал добавить, но к сожалению всё осталось так-же( Звука нет. А если бы была ошибка по пути файла то выдало бы ошибку. Но ошибки нет значит файл находит, но по каким либо причинам не может его воспроизвести.

Comment: Всё таки попытайтесь убедиться в том, что действительно подцепляете нужный файл (и он "здоровый"), например, через точку останова. Еще, как вариант, можно добавить эту запись в состав файлов проекта или ресурсы и тащить от туда. Проверьте также работают ли у Вас системные звуки `SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play()`.

Comment: Спасибо за совет попробую отпишу. Ещё вопрос я же могу добавить SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play() в саму форму после инициализации что-бы когда форма загрузилась звук воспроизвелся?

Comment: По идее, возможно добавление `SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play()` в любое место Вашей программы, поскольку производится обращение к пространству имен `System.Media`, которое, при использовании соответствующей директивы, доступно где угодно. В данном случае - в обработчике события загрузки формы.